# Add more than 1 timestamp on one Excel Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp

I have some issue...

I have a work sheet to track CRM pipeline activities and every status changed will be recorded by a time stamp... but, I don't know how to make more than one time stamp...

Here the condition:

- Cell "A" will be as Range and Trigger, Then Cell "B" will be as
  target timestamp I.
- Cell "G" will be as Range and Trigger, Then Cell "H" will be as target timestamp II.
- Cell "P" will be as Range and Trigger, Then Cell "Q" will be as target timestamp III.
- Cell "AA" will be as Range and Trigger, Then Cell "AB" will be as target timestamp IV.
- The Range and Trigger Values can be as number and/or text.

This my Worksheet Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myTableRange1 As Range
Dim myTrigger1 As Range
Dim myUpdatedRange1 As Range

'Your data table range
Set myTableRange1 = Range("B6:B50000")

'Check if the changed cell is in the data tabe or not.
If Intersect(Target, myTableRange1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Stop events from running
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Column for the date/time
Set myTrigger1 = Range("B" & Target.Row)

'Column for last updated date/time
Set myUpdatedRange1 = Range("G" & Target.Row)

'Determine if the input date/time should change
If myTrigger1.Value = "" Then

myUpdatedRange1.Value = Now   

End If

'Update the updated date/time value
myUpdatedRange1.Value = Now

'Turn events back on
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A Worksheet Change: Multiple Timestamp Columns

- This will add a timestamp only if the 'timestamp cell' is blank.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const FirstRow As Long = 6
    Const ColumnsRangeAddress As String = "A:A,G:G,P:P,AA:AA"
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Intersect(Rows(FirstRow) _
        .Resize(Rows.Count - FirstRow + 1), Range(ColumnsRangeAddress))
    
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(srg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim iCell As Range
    
    For Each iCell In irg.Cells ' 'A,G,P,AA'
        With iCell.Offset(, 1) ' 'B,H,Q,AB'
            If Len(CStr(.Value)) = 0 Then ' is blank
                If drg Is Nothing Then
                    Set drg = .Cells
                Else
                    Set drg = Union(drg, .Cells)
                End If
            'Else ' is not blank; do nothing
            End If
        End With
    Next iCell
    
    If drg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False ' before writing
    drg.Value = Now
    Application.EnableEvents = True ' after writing

End Sub
```

Comment: i full use your code but didnt work sir.. this i upload my file...

Comment: this sir, your code here.. and i test didt work.. may i put on the wrong cell or something...
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IO2lnJl30W1r1tiA95bpgiMFwGmLmR0x/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That's a nice workbook. You must have spent hours creating it. Now spend a few seconds testing from row 6 to the bottom.

Comment: Wow.. so "Const FirstRow As Long = 6" determide First Row.. OMG... hha..... Youre the master....thank you sir... :)

Comment: Btw Sir, how to enabling the Date Changing when the data change...

Comment: oke, i just found sir.. i add

If Len(CStr(.Value)) <> 0 Then ' is blank
                If drg Is Nothing Then
                    Set drg = .Cells
                Else
                    Set drg = Union(drg, .Cells)
                End If
            'Else ' is not blank; do nothing
            End If

And works

Comment: Sir, is it possible to change this >  With iCell.Offset(, 1) to targeted cells? so not using offset.. because on some data, the time stamp cells are not located after the cells data..
Example : F:C , G:H ... WHere the front cells is the data and the pair is the time stamp cells.

Comment: I consider this question answered. Your follow-up question should be a new one. This code belongs to anyone so feel free to copy it (modified for your case) into a new question, describe what it does (`A, G, P, AA` with offset), and describe what you want it to do (e.g. `F` to `C`, `G` to `H`, etc. I am sure that many contributors will be able to help you. A screenshot of your worksheet (a better one than the worksheet you provided the link for) might help as would a link to this question.